# Resize ImageView to height of a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

My LinearLayout contains 2 TextViews (TextView1 and TextView2) and one ImageView. Now I want the LinearLayout to always have a fixed height, the height of ThextView1, so that the ImageView resizes its Image with fill_parent always to the height of TextView1.

```
 _____________________________________
|TextView1------------------ ImageView|
|TextView1 --- TextView2 --- ImageView|
|TextView1 ----------------- ImageView|
```

Kind of hard to explain... The ImageView always should have the height of the TextView1 and resize its image (while keeping the original aspectratio).

Is this possible to do just with the layout-xml, or do i need to do that programmatically?

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

I haven't tested this. Is this what you are referring to?